# Rational function on polydisc

Tags: several-complex-variables

Who has idea to prove this:

Let $\mathbb{U}^n$ be a polydisc, $f\in \mathcal{O}(\mathbb{U}^n)\cap C(\bar{\mathbb{U}}^n)$, if $|f|=const$ on the skeleton of $\mathbb{U}^n$, then $f$ must be a rational function.